# Service run on specific Time Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am trying to run service on every day only on Specific time,
lets say every day 8 :00 am 
and here I found two methods as

```
public static void setScheduleMessage(Context context, int hours,
        int minuts, int seconds) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // 8 AM
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MessageSchduledService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            pendingIntent);
}
```

But problem with this method is, it is running every hour after specified time.

and here is second method I used which is not executing my service ?

```
public static void setScheduleMessage2(Context context, int hours,
        int minuts, int seconds) {
    Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());// set the current

     // time and date for

     // this calendar
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageSchduledService.class);

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);

}
```

POST :
In my app  I just want to push message from my app Database to Message Data base at specific time every day.
please if anybody having an idea about this, then let me know what i am doing wrong in these methods ?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [Alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)
@  RTC examples

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

or

In your code

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);
```

replace

> AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY

to

> 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

. which means repeat alarm exactly after 24 hours

Comment: Thanks Vinay, I have one more question that suppose if i set above alarm for every day. and later i restart my device then, Does it still alarm work on every day basis ? Or I need to have boot complete broadcast and set alarm again in that ?

Comment: Need to have boot complete broadcast and set alarm again, you can save time in shared preference.

Comment: So if one uses setInexactRepeating() one cannot specify a time oneself but rather MUST use the interval constants?

Comment: @Mafro34 - Not necessary - you can refer the document here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29