# Android AlaramManager of android not triggering at defined time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want to trigger alarm with my song at specified time, below is what I've done :

This is in the java file :

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void startMusic(View view) {

    Integer hr = timepickerStart.getCurrentHour();
    Integer min = timepickerStart.getCurrentMinute();


    // Start service using AlarmManager

    if(selectedFile != null && selectedFile.length() > 0)

    {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this,MusicPlayActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, selectedFile.getPath());
        PendingIntent pendingIndent =   PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Before Present time in mili" + firingCal.getTimeInMillis());
        firingCal.add(Calendar.HOUR, hr);
        firingCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        firingCal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();

        System.out.println("After setting Present time in mili" + firingCal.getTimeInMillis());

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIndent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set from today", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select music File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Now in manifest file

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The issue is it starts on its own will.

Exmaple :

If the mobile time is `9:30 AM 2/12/2013 (DD/MM/YYYY)`, and I select the Trigger time at `10:00 AM` on the same day. This will not trigger at `10:00 AM` at all, it will trigger the next day that is `3/12/2013` some different time that too not at `10:00 AM`

I am not able to judge the timing properly.

Comment: Not able to trigger at exact time.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159304/service-run-on-specific-time-android/20159438#20159438

Comment: Sure I would try just now added

Comment: int hr = timepickerStart.getCurrentHour();
     int min = timepickerStart.getCurrentMinute();
firingCal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
      firingCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
      firingCal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0); also did above changes now also i am not able to trigger at right time

Comment: I would try it out with the files you gave me

Comment: thank you very very much Shakeeb Ayaz.. thanks a lot.. it is now working.. i was trying for .. more that 2 weeks..that a lot

Comment: replaced add with Set

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are using wrapper class(`Integer`) to store hour and min simply use `int` variable

**Set** value to calender not **add** to calender

```
        firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hr);//better use Calander.HOUR_OF_DAY bcoz hour range is 0 to 11 HOUR_OF_DAY 0 23 bcoz of this also your alarm is triggering next day
        firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Comment: int hr = timepickerStart.getCurrentHour(); int min = timepickerStart.getCurrentMinute(); firingCal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr); firingCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min); firingCal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0); also did above changes now also i am not able to trigger at right time

Comment: instead of `firingCal.add` use `firingCal.set`..Read answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some simple alarm manager demo,which is working fine in my case,try and if it works fine for you than implement same in your code

Here is my [MainActivity](http://pastie.org/8522193)

Here is [MyReceiver](http://pastie.org/8522195) Class

Here is [AlarmActivity](http://pastie.org/8522197) class

And here are layout xml files

[activity_main.xml](http://pastie.org/8522198)

[alarmview.xml](http://pastie.org/8522200)

In AlarmActivity at line number 76 this line `mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);` is responsible for muting alarm sound,if you don't want to mute it than simply comment that line.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> add this permission,i gave u all code,make habit to search something

Comment: @user2045810 nice to hear this